# Textures won't show up when I render an animation

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing

I have a problem with Blender and its animation process, I want to do an animation and to do that I rendered all frames of my project. Textures on all of my frames are visible but when I do the render animation, my textures won't show up. I used UV/Image editor, I applied the materials to the objects and I did the exact same thing for 3 other animation and it has worked on all of them..

Here is a rendered frame where we can see that textures show up.
[image: textures on]

On this screenshot we can see that there's no textures when I do render the animation but on the right screen we have a view in "Render Mode" which shows us textures...
[image: textures off]

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful

Comment: Could you upload your blend file if possible? http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/n0iqdwr8g7dacls/Building_courbe2.blend . I couldn't upload it on pasteall because my file is too big .

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. For me both f12 (render) and ctrl + f12 (render animation) work just fine.

Comment: Yes for me too but if you use the video sequence editor by using all the frames you have rendered, textures won't show up. That's my problem :/

Comment: You should save out the images and than after rendering them you should load them back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a *scene* strip above your rendered image sequence, which will display the same thing as the default viewport in solid shading (no textures), unless you set it to something else like *textured* or *rendered* (rendered will be very slow because it has to render each frame. You also have to disable *openGL preview* for rendered to work):

[image]

However, assuming the image sequence below it is the rendered animation, then you can just remove the scene strip.